# 'StartsWith' not working in Linq-To-EF

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have implemented a Linq-to-EF expression using the sting comparison 'StartsWith', but it is behaving like the string comparison 'Contains'... my code is:

```
string ubi = '12';

return (from u in _dataContext.Notice
where u.UB.StartsWith(ubi)
select new AutoCompleteData { Value = u.UB }).Distinct().Take(50);
```

I would expect the data returned to be only values that start with '12'...but it returns values like '44412' and '312' as well as '1245' and '1299'.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: EF version used? Database type? Generated SQL? In my environment - EF6.1.3, SqlServer, works as expected (generates `WHERE table.Field LIKE '12%`)

Comment: using Visual Studio 2012, .net framework 4.5. I tried to get the version of EF and got 3.5.0.0. Using SQL Server. The generated SQL is using CHARINDEX... Full SQL Statement is: "SELECT [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], [Limit1].[UBI] AS [UBI] FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP (50) [Extent1].[UBI] AS [UBI], t1 AS [C1] FROM [dbo].[Notice] AS [Extent1] WHERE (CAST(CHARINDEX(@p__linq__5, [Extent1].[UBI]) AS int)) = 1 )  AS [Limit1]"

Comment: Hmm, even if a quite different, it should work as expected according to [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) documentation. Sorry, I have no idea why is not working in your case.

Comment: It's really strange...thx anyways. If no one else has any ideas, I guess I will just have to live with it and hope none of the end users will notice/complain about it. I am using it for an AutoComplete feature in an ASP.net website, so should still be helpful.

Comment: I think you refer to the .Net version, which would mean that you have EF v1 here. If so, either try to upgrade your dev environment to a higher .Net version + EF6, or move to LINQ-to-SQL if you can. L2S is superior to EF1.